# Cannot find fontawesome.mf

Tags: fonts, texstudio, paths

Currently having an error, I'm trying to use this https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV . It used to work super well with vscode. Now I'm trying to use it with TeX Studio but when I compile it gives me this error:

```
name = FontAwesome, rootname = FontAwesome, 
pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!   

kpathsea: Running mktexmf FontAwesome.mf 
The command name is C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\mktexmf 
Cannot find FontAwesome.mf.
```

The log is:

```
Font TU/FontAwesome(1)/m/n/6.8=FontAwesome at 6.8pt not loadable: 
Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

Font TU/Roboto(1)/m/n/32=Roboto-Thin at 32.0pt not loadable: 
Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
```

I already have the fonts installed on my computer too ...

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. It's best not to post a link to the code in the question as links might die or the content might change (if I go to the repository now, will the problem still be there?). Rather, you should provide a Minimal Working Example: A short code that starts in the `documentclass` and ends in the `\end{document}` which recreates your problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by using

```
\newfontfamily{\FA}{fontawesome.otf}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{roboto.otf}
```

Instead of

```
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{Roboto}
```

Comment: Do `fc-match "FontAwesome"` and `luaotfload-tool --find "FontAwesome"` locate the font? If not, you might need to use the family name as it appears in the font.

Comment: You also don’t want to redefine `\FA` twice; hiding `FontAwesome`. Surely you want to use two different font families?